# NUMA_NODE for 10GbE device

Tags: debian, 10gbethernet, numa

My server reports numa_node=-1 for all ethernet devices. I am interested in high speed UDP capture (all jumbo packets). I am running Debian Wheezy (kernel  3.2.68-1+deb7u2). I am told that one needs to pin the data receiving process to the NUMA node closest to the NiC (an Intel 82599EB on a  PCIe x8 slot and ixgbe driver). Is there a way to find out on which NUMA node is my ethernet card hooked to?

Comment: You'll need to look at the docs for the particular server that you are using. What model is it?

Comment: Hi @Zypher, this is H8DGT from Supermicro hosting 2xAMD Opetron 6276

Answer (score 1):

According to the chip set diagram in the [manual for that board](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/SR56x0/MNL-H8DGT-HF-HIBQF.pdf) The single PCI slot is hooked into CPU1. You can see the diagram on page 14 of the linked PDF.

Comment: Thanks @Zypher, that does answer my question. I am still somewhat puzzled by the OS reporting numa_node=-1. A somewhat older mother board H8DM8-2 correctly reports numa_node=0.

Comment: Yea no idea why that happens. All I can suggest is upgrade your firmware and make sure you have any management tools from supermicro installed